# Nested objects in javascript how to freeze it?

Tags: freeze, jscript, nest-nested-object

I am trying to freeze javascript nested object. As I am new to JS I am facing difficulty to freeze the nested objects.

```
const obj = { prop: { innerProp: 1 } };
obj.prop.innerProp = 5;
console.log(obj.prop.innerProp); // 5
```

Is it possible do freeze nested objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example to freeze nested objects

```
function deepFreeze (o) {
Object.freeze(o);
if (o === undefined) {
return o;
}

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(o).forEach(function (prop) {
if (o[prop] !== null
&& (typeof o[prop] === "object" || typeof o[prop] === "function")
&& !Object.isFrozen(o[prop])) {
  deepFreeze(o[prop]);
}
});

return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) which is a library for working with immutable values. Moreover, in terms of performance, especially if you constantly make use of immutable variables in project, [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) is a great choice, since `deepFreeze` more costly in terms of performance.